# What does it mean {...a11yProps(0)} in the component property?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Consider the following code snippet of a component:

```
...
...

function a11yProps(index: any) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,
  };
}

...
...

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs value={value} onChange={handleChange} aria-label="simple tabs example">
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        Item One
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        Item Two
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        Item Three
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I struggle to understand the following component implementation:

```
<Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
```

What does `{...a11yProps(0)}`  mean? Does it mean I pass here properties?

When I look at the API documentation of [Tab](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/), I can not find the `id` and `aria-controls` properties.

The whole code https://codesandbox.io/s/kz25m

Comment: These properties are html element properties and probably `Tab` passes them all to the resulting html element.

Comment: Properties are expanded, Id and aria-controls. Aria is a set of properties used to create [accessible ui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA), thus the actual control docs could miss it.

Answer (score 4):

It is a spread operator (... is Javascript spread operator). It basically de-structures / spreads out the value from an array or object.

In your sample code I see your function returns some javascript object.  This spread operator pulls out / de-structures all the values from the object and gives each individual values as output

```
{... a11yProps(0)} 
==> This would return -> {...{id: `simple-tab-0`,aria-controls: `simple-tabpanel-0`}} 
==> on spreading out the values from the object it would look like 
=> {id: `simple-tab-0`,aria-controls: `simple-tabpanel-0`}
```

Another example with spread operator

```
let d = {...{"a":1, "b":2, "c":3}}


output: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
```

Please refer to ES6 website for more on spread operator, destructuring - http://es6-features.org/#SpreadOperator

Answer (score 3):

It's just a function for making a dynamic object and using them as props, to reduce code size.

```
<Tab label="Item One" id="simple-tab-0" ariaControls="simple-tabpanel-0"/>
```

About TypeScript and Docs: If you ctrl + click on the Material-UI component, you can see they extends types of component with `React.ElementType` and inside of this, you can find `JSX.IntrinsicElements` and each one of HTML element has `React.DetailedHTMLProps` with props of `HTMLAttributes` extended with `AriaAttributes` and `DOMAttributes`. So naturally, you can pass all of the available attributes for that tag on them!

Comment: However on the API documentation, I can not the both props, why?? Why the compiler does not complain??

Comment: `id` is used for all HTML element, and `aria-controls` used for making tabs, because compiler didn't complain about docs its just a JSX attribute.

Comment: Consider the following code https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-0ggw3?file=/src/index.tsx. As you can see, I provide here `<App id="Hello" />` ID and it shows me error message, why?

Comment: As I understand, `id` is used for all HTML element and the compiler should not complain.

Comment: In typescript, usually properties are defined as `interface` and the interface of `Tab` does not provide the `id` and `aria-controls` properties. Why create dynamic properties are possible?

Comment: If you right-click on Material-UI component, you can see they extend HTML elements attributes for their component.

Comment: I can not find the extension, can you please guide me through.

Comment: I dont have extention for that, its just vs code and typescript. Oh im sorry i told you wrong, ctrl and click on material ui component, redirects you to node mudole file.